# Appending data from excel spreadsheet to Access

Tags: excel, append, ms-access-2010, database-normalization

Background: I have a large Access database that is already normalized into many tables. This database will be constantly updated with more data. The data I receive will be in the form of a spreadsheet. It is unpractical to manually enter all the data into Access.

It sounds like the way to do so would be to append the spreadsheet. I have turned the spreadsheet into the same format as the database, and corrected all the data types to be the same as I have them in the database. The only issue I see so far is that it does not normalize the data into tables that I already have set up. Does anyone know how to append data into Access and have it normalize to the way I have everything set up? The table analyzer wizard will not let me split the table into the same way I have them originally, due to repeating names.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, your spreadsheet has data for multiple tables in the same row of the same sheet? If so, the easiest approach may be to write a VBA module to extract and append/update the tables. You may be able to (1) import sheet into Access; (2) Write query to select fields for 'table1' and append; (3) repeat step 2 as many times as needed.

Comment: Hi Wayne, thank you for your response. I think I understand what you mean. I just tried this, and yes it adds the information to the tables, but it does not recognize duplicated values. For example, I have a table named "Type" with 3 records (Interior, Exterior, Both). If I append the imported datasheet to the Type table, then it adds 30 more records of the repeating types.

Comment: Change that query to use 'GROUP BY', thus will only add one record... test as a SELECT query first

Comment: Thank you! This works great. Now I'm coming across the issue on how to connect them all together. Of course I have the PK and FK's that I could manually enter and match up..but that would take a long time. Is there an easier route to connect the information that I append?

Comment: It all depends on your schema and how the data in Excel relates to that. If you have columns in Excel for 'EmployeeName', 'WkEndDt' and HrsWorked'  Then tables in Access 'tblEmployee' that contains fields ID [PK], EmpName [text, unique], and table 'tblHours' with fields EmpID, WkEndDt, HrsWorked, then yes, there is a way to match up the keys. I can't be more specific unless I know the columns you have in Excel, the required tables and fields in Access and a map of where fields go.

Comment: My excel sheet contains columns such as: Date, Project, ProductCode, ProductName, Test, Result. My database has a Product table, which includes the FKs of ProductCode, ProductName, Date, etc. The Name and Code of the product has to have its own table because these products get tested several times. The Product table also connects to the Results table. In the results table, I have a FK to the TestNames table, because there are many different tests performed. This is just a general idea of what I have. I actually have 10 lookup tables coming from the Product table.

Comment: Best I can tell from your description, the 'Product' table is where you would start. Assuming you have a constraint to prevent duplicates: (1) write a query to add unmatched products. (2) Not sure what the 'date' field is for in the product table. (3) Write a query to add unmatched 'TestNames'. (4) Add query to add unmatched 'Results' records (based on the Product and Test). I assume your Excel sheet only allows valid product names, test names, etc.? (5) Add any other queries needed to relate to other tables.